# Embeded IF statment in gridview component

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I would like to have a condition in one of my Grid-view's column,which it may contains a number string (6-10 digits) or characters (3-6). Something like :

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="HL_Number" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Code")%>' Target="_blank"
NavigateUrl='<%# "http://www.address.com/" +  Eval("Code")%>'> Visible='<%  (IsNumber(Eval("Code"))==true)? true:false  %>'
</asp:HyperLink>

<br />

<asp:HyperLink ID="HL_String" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Code")%>' Target="_blank"
NavigateUrl='<%# "~/PDF/" +  Eval("Code")+"pdf" %>'   Visible='<%  (IsNumber(Eval("Code"))==false)? true:false  %>'>
</asp:HyperLink>
```

One of HyperLink must be visible at the same time, how can i perform it? Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

From a good design perspective, move this logic to your business layer. Let's say this is your entity

```
public class MyEntity
{
   public int Id {get;set;}
   // ... some other properties
   public string Code {get;set;}

   // if you need some other control to be visible based on 
   // whether Code is a number or not, use this to bind to Visible property. 
   // Note, this is not required in case of HyperLink
   public bool IsVisible
   {
     { get {return IsNumber(Code); }
   }
   public string NavigateUrl
   { 
      get { return GetUrl(Code); }
   }
   private bool IsNumber(string code) { // your method body here }
   private string GetUrl(string code)
   {
       if(!IsNumber(code))
       {
          return string.Format("~/PDF/{0}pdf", code);
       }

       return string.Format("http://www.address.com/{0}",code);
   }
}
```

Assuming your datasource is collection of MyEntity objects.

```
    var dataSource = // some method that returns collection of MyEntity objects, 
                     // for example List<MyEntity>
    myGridView.DataSource = dataSource;
    myGridView.DataBind();
```

Now, keep only 1 `HyperLink` control in your GridView and bind it to respective properties.

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="HL_String" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Code")%>' Target="_blank"
               NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("NavigateUrl") %>'>
</asp:HyperLink>
```