# If check on DataBound Control?

Tags: c#, asp.net

How do you correctly check a `concatenated string` for length in asp.net?

If the total length of `Eval("FirstName")` and `Eval("LastName")`is longer than 21 I want to shorten the string and add "..." to the end.

```
<span id="userNameText">
        <%if (string.Concat(Eval("FirstName"), " ", Eval("LastName")).ToString().Length > 21)
          {
              string.Concat(Eval("FirstName"), " ", Eval("LastName")).ToString().PadRight(19).Substring(0, 19).TrimEnd() + "...";
          }
          else
          {
              string.Concat(Eval("FirstName"), " ", Eval("LastName"));
          }
        %>
    </span>
```

Comment: Do you consider doing this check (and essentially moving this whole logic) to your domain class (or ideally model for your UI) ?
I posted [answer to similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29367537/embeded-if-statment-in-gridview-component/29367887#29367887). Check it, maybe you will agree that it is more elegant way of dealing with your case.

Comment: @Michael Yeah you may be right.. I may just move it to a `<span>` and do it with jQuery

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Is it permissible to "bump" a question with a comment like this to see if the author considered my reply, or prompt them to mark the proper answer if there appears to be at least one correct answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a helper method to accomplish this...

```
public static string Truncate(string source, int length)
{
if (source.Length > length)
{
    source = String.Concat(source.Substring(0, length), " ...");
}
return source;
}

<span id="userNameText">
    <%= Truncate(string.Concat(Eval("FirstName"), " ", Eval("LastName")).ToString(), 21) %>
</span>
```

https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/71148/truncate-string-method

Answer (score 0):

You can not use if else with Eval, instead you can use ternary operator in c#(?:)

```
<span id="userNameText">
    <%# (string.Concat(Eval("FirstName"), " ", Eval("LastName")).ToString().Length > 21) ? string.Concat(Eval("FirstName"), " ", Eval("LastName")).ToString().PadRight(19).Substring(0,19).TrimEnd() + "..." : string.Concat(Eval("FirstName"), " ", Eval("LastName")) %>
</span>
```